# Как взять данные из SELECT-a?

Tags: php, html, ajax

```
$(function() {

    $(".search_button").click(function() {
        // получаем то, что написал пользователь
        var searchString    = $("#search_box").val();
        // формируем строку запроса
        var data            = 'search='+ searchString;

        // если searchString не пустая
        if(searchString) {
            // делаем ajax запрос
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "do_search.php",
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function(html) { // запустится до вызова запроса
                    $("#results").html('');
                    $("#searchresults").show();
                    $(".word").html(searchString);
               },
               success: function(html){ // запустится после получения результатов
                    $("#results").show();
                    $("#results").append(html);
              }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

это код ajax. 
  `name: Select name='list' >...`
Таким образом я создала список, из 4 строк. select id не имеет.

Что мне добавить в ajax или в html, чтобы оно взяла, точнее передала и данные Selecta в другую файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В форму вставляете тег `select`. В `input` и `select` прописываете атрибут `name`. В js меняете значение data.

```
var data = $('form').serialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = new Object();
data.search = searchString;
data.select_text = $('select[name="list"] option:selected').text();
data.select_val = $('select[name="list"] option:selected').val();
```